# PGRouting: build path without shortcuts

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I create a pathfinding algorithm using `pgrouting` library. This is the ouput I get with `pgr_dijkstra`:

[image]

However, I do not need the shortcuts I'm having here. What are the possible approaches to make sure the red path will be built right down on a blue line?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add a sample data and the query you wrote? preferably in a fiddle

Comment: @JimJones, the question has been moved here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409136/pgrouting-build-path-without-shortcuts?noredirect=1#comment665973_409136